# Android in-tree build: include *.so library to apk instead of link to /system/lib/

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I have a package integrated to Android 5.0 sources. It has a java service and a couple of native libraries. When I build it I get an apk with symbolic links to native libs (in `/system/lib64/`) and it's supposed that libs are already there. I have to make the package installable from app market, that is all libs must be included to the apk. I could get such an apk with SDK, but I cannot use it because I have dependencies on non-public libs and java classes.

How can I build apk in-tree so that my native libs are included in `apk` itself?

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on the libs you want to use.

If you rely on libssl.so and libcrypto.so, you should compile your own version of OpenSSL, include and use it from your APK.

For other system libs that are officially part of the NDK (libc.so, libandroid.so...), there is no need to symbolic link anything, they will automatically be loaded from the system.

If you really need to use non-public libs and classes, you can do so, by loading directly the libs from the system, it doesn't make sense to embed a copy of these. However it may be a big source of crashes to use anything private, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I have my own libs and use a few non-public ones. When I build in-tree my own libs go to /system/lib, not to apk. Can I change it somehow? I'd like to avoid getting  every non-public function via dlsym if it's possible...

Comment: Then, you can manually copy your own libs to the libs/*ABI*/ subfolders of your Android project and build it. But it would be even better if you could manage to build everything out of the tree, your app and your libs, against ndk platform headers and libraries. That's the best way to ensure it will correctly work across devices. That will also allow you to easily support all the different cpu architectures Android devices are using.

Comment: I am having the same problem, and I don't consider this as any help at all. It is more like a comment. I have an APK that uses its own JNI lib, but that lib is build to /system/lib, which makes my APK non-installable/upgradable. And that was the only point in making it an APK!

Comment: I'd like to help more, but it isn't possible if you don't provide more details on what setup you have and what result you want to achieve. You may even have a different problem than the original poster one's, so maybe you should open a new question.